# iFrame with popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm doing an iframe with a coverage map in. It has a button "click to view coverage map" and then when you click on it a window opens with the map but the button and the new window has the same URL. It kinda looks like an overlay or pop-up window. Since it has the same URL i decided to use the button instead, but if you click on the button the coverage map obviously doesn't show because the iframe is so small.

How could i incorporate that into my code? Here's my code

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 8px auto; max-width: 196px;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://www.axxess.co.za/mobile/data" style="border: 0px none; height: 613px; margin-top: -575px; width: 1583px; margin-left: -1077px;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an iframe to a page where the button is. Show the code for the button. How does it open the popup. I have visited the axxess.co.za website and it does look like an overlay. So show the code. Or is it an external overlay you want to embed?

Comment: that is the coed for the button. I'm not sure what the code should be for the overlay to show the coverage map. if i could just show the overlay and not the button that would be great.